# Return php value from ComboBox

Tags: php, sql

i create a combobox with sql values but how i know what the value selected?
this is my code, have a lot of scrap but is my tests :)
I link to send the selected option to another php file already created.

```
    <?php
    require_once('auth.php');
    require_once('config.php');
    require_once('no-cache-headers.php');
    require_once('functions.php');

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Nova Mensagem</title>
<link href="Formatacao.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Bem-vindo <?php echo $_SESSION['USERNAME'];?></h1>

<form id="regForm" name="regForm" method="post" action="verificarMensagem.php">
  <table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>

   <?php

mysql_connect('localhost','comunicat','comunicat');


mysql_select_db('Comunicat');

 $iduser =$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];

$query="Select * from Usuarios where id <> '$iduser'";


$resultado=mysql_query($query);
echo '<select name=”Nome”>';


while($linha=mysql_fetch_array($resultado))
{


echo '<option value="' . $linha['ID'] . '">' . $linha['Nome'] . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
?>
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="mensagem" id="mensagem">
</textarea>

      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Enviar" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: OT: Don't use curly quotes in HTML.

Comment: Use `mysqli_`, also look into prepared statements.

Comment: `”` beautiful, yet deadly.

Answer (score 0):

You can get value of select element in php by using $_POST[name-of-element]:

```
<?php
    echo $_POST['Nome'];
?>
```

That works also with checkboxs,radios,etc

Comment: <form method="post" ...>
<select name=”Nome”>
..
</form>
means you must have $_POST['Nome']

Comment: Sorry for my NB but appear that the "Undefined index: Nome"

Comment: $_POST['Nome'] must be in landing file (<form action="landing.php"...), or in same file if your action="" or action="(this_file)"

Comment: maybe the best way is to follow some tutorial and then after you understand how post works, you will be able to write  your script correctly

Answer (score 0):

When the form that contains your "combobox" is submitted, you can get the selected value from your combobox with the line of code below:

```
$val = $_POST['Nome']; // if the form was submitted using post method
$val = $_GET['Nome']; // if the form was submitted using get method
```

**NB**
Do not use mysql_* no more, it is officially deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: Yes, but the php code contains a HTML form with id = regForm. So using the code I posted, you can get your combobox value on the "verificarMensagem.php" page.

Comment: Undefined index: Nome in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sir1415/Comunicat/novaMensagem.php on line 53

Comment: You have action="verificarMensagem.php" on your form, it means that the form values should be posted to that page. That is where you can get your form values. But you need the form values in the file "novaMensagem.php", then you have to the replace it with the value in your form's action attribute.

Comment: And who i call for this variables?